# server side pagination in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatable, pagination

I am having displaying datas. Because it contains more than 1000 rows of data. I want to have a server side pagination instead of what jquery datatable offers. As i have noticed, datatables load all the 1000 queries and does client side pagination only.
This is my controller

```
 function view_ftth_report()
{

    if ($this->data['permission_ftth_report'] == '1') {
    $this->load->model('staff_activity_model');
    $this->data['records'] = $this->staff_activity_model->view_ftth_report();

    $this->data['main_template'] = 'staff_activity/staff_activity_main';
    $this->data['inner_template'] = 'staff_activity/ftth/staff_activity_ftth_report_view';
    $this->data['inner_nav'] = 'staff_activity/staff_activity_nav';
    $this->load->view('common/common', $this->data);
        }
    else{
        $this->data['main_template'] = 'staff_activity/staff_activity_main';
        $this->data['inner_template'] = 'staff_activity/staff_activity_denied';
        $this->data['inner_nav'] = 'staff_activity/staff_activity_nav_denied';
        $this->load->view('common/common', $this->data);
    }
}
```

This is my model.

```
function view_ftth_report(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ct_staff_activity_ftth ORDER BY date DESC limit 20  ";
    $data = array();
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    foreach($result->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

And this is my view. I have used ajax to call the records .

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $("#data_tbl").dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 50
    });

});
</script>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="box ">
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>staff_activity/date_report_index"><button style="margin: 15px; padding: 10px; border-radius: 10px; border-collapse: collapse " class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Filter By Date</button></a>

                    <div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-responsive" id="data_tbl">
                            <h4>Recent Entries</h4>
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Sn.</th>
                                <th>Client's Name</th>
                                <th>Address</th>
                                <th>Fiber Length</th>
                                <th>Phone Number</th>
                                <th>Package</th>
                                <th>Result</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Team Name</th>
                                <th>Remarks</th>
                                <th>Edit</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>

                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="result">
 <?php

                            $count = 0;

                            foreach($records as $rec){
                                $count = $count+1;

                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $rec['client_name']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $rec['address']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $rec['fiber_length']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $rec['phone_number']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $rec['package']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $rec['result']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $rec['date']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $rec['team_name']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $rec['remarks']; ?></td>
                                    <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>staff_activity/edit_ftth_report/<?php echo $rec['id']?>">Edit</a></td>
                                    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="chk('<?php echo base_url(); ?>staff_activity/delete_ftth_report/<?php echo $rec['id']  ?>')">Delete</a></td>

                                </tr>

                                <?php

                            }

                            ?>
                            </tbody>

                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also Integrate `DataTable` recently in my project.
Actually in `codeigniter` there is some `library` available for `DataTable`.
Please find the below some useful `libraries`

1. [Ignited-Datatables](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables)
2. [Codeigniter-DataTables](https://github.com/zepernick/Codeigniter-DataTables)

So you just follow the instraction given in `readme`. 
I am providing example for **Ignited-Datatables** which i integrate in my project .

**CODEIGNITER**

1. First move `DataTable.php` in your `application\library` folder.
2. Load in your `controller`'s  `constructor`

   `$this->load->library('Datatables');`
3. `$this->datatables->select( pass the column which you want to display in table and manage order also respect to your table)`.
4. `$this->datatables->from('ct_staff_activity_ftth');` Pass the Table name here.

**JAVASCRIPT**

1. Include [dataTable.min.js](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiRs4K_5sfNAhWBO48KHVMgCrsQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.net%2Fdownload%2F&usg=AFQjCNGl8QE60-Yi3vcW_1cdOHmifT4dPQ&sig2=YarlK9UCKXGRXIYJLHM1VQ&bvm=bv.125596728,d.c2I&cad=rja) in your view file.
2. Put the code in `document ready` stage.

   `$('#data_tbl').dataTable( {
           processing: true,
           serverSide: true,
           ajax: {
               "url": "/index.php/DataTableExample/dataTable",
               "type": "POST"
           },
           columns: [
               { data: "s.s_name" },
               {data : "c.c_name"},
               {data : "c.c_zip"},
               { data: "$.city_state_zip" } //refers to the expression in the "More Advanced DatatableModel Implementation"
           ],
       aaSorting: [
               [0, 'desc'] // provide the default sorting column with order numer.
           ]
       });`

Hope it will help you. if you need any further assistance let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will go through your answer. Will get back to you if i need further help